# When I opened the Software centre, I could not see any application. I am getting an error when I try to reinstall it

Tags: apt, software-center

I could not see applications when I opened Software Center. When I tried to reinstall I got an error message:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 8394 (apt-get)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

Please help me resolve the above issue.

Comment: Check you haven't a terminal session open performing a package operation (esp. waiting for you to answer a question such as a Y to proceed)

Answer (score 1):

Explore with `ps -fp8394`. If process 8394 exists, you (or `unattended-updates`) are updating the packaging system elsewhere.

If process 8394 does not exist, the lock file may be left over from an update interrupted by a sudden reboot. If so, it should be deleted, BUT your packaging system may be in an inconsistent state.

Do

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and Read the Error Messages.

An alternative explanation for `ps -fp8394` being empty may be that process 8394 has finished, and deleted the lock file.